# How do I disable the two other vercel.app domains for a deployed project?

Tags: vercel

I added a custom domain to Vercel but noticed that it also created two additional domains on vercel.app (one for deployment and one for the branch). There are two reasons the is really bad for me. First, accessing the website on the other domains bypasses my Cloudflare rules. Second, the DB is configured to only accept traffic from the first domain.

I can't find how to disable these anywhere. Help would be appreciated.